# How Do I Detect if a User Already Likes My Facebook Page when landing on my site without user_likes permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

When a user lands on my website I would like to present him with a litebox with the like facebook widget in it. However I only want to do this if they haven't already liked our facebook page.

I want to make this process seamless so I dont want to have to ask for permission first.

I read somewhere that if its for your own sites FB page, then you dont require this.

But cant find any more information other than a person stating this in the stackoverflow.

Any help much appreciated.

thanks

andy

Comment: This is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to go through the [review process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) with the user_likes permission. Facebook will not approved `user_likes` for that, because like gating is not allowed anymore.

It was possible earlier to check if a user liked a Page directly in a Page Tab/App, but that flag was removed.